# HTML5 File API: Is there any limitation in the chunk size of an uploaded file?

Tags: javascript, html, fine-uploader, fileapi

I'm using the [FineUploader](https://fineuploader.com/) library to upload files of, about, 5GB. Everything works well with a chunk size of 1MB, but I think this size is pretty small and I want to increase it. So I tried with 10MB and it stopped working. Trying with other sizes, I discovered that from 4MB and more, the upload stops working. What's going on here? Is it a limitation of the File API or the browser (I tried with Chrome and Firefox)?

Comment: browsers and servers, https://docs.fineuploader.com/features/chunking.html -- File chunking also provides a workaround for request size limits put in place by browsers (e.g., Firefox and Chrome limit upload request sizes to about 4GB) and servers (e.g. [PHP's post_max_size][postmaxsize]).

Comment: Yes, that's the total length of the file, but how about the chunk size?

Comment: The link goes into more detail, each chunk is sent as a separate file allowing you to get past the file size limit, I did not answer the question because, I don't have a clue which resource, (operating system, browser, or server), is stopping you. HTML5 allows browsers etc to set limits and finalize the standard.

Comment: Per the link, dated 2013, a chunk size of 2MB -- "qqchunksize": 2000000 -- is the standard setting on servers.

Comment: @Wayne The server is IIS, I'm using ASP.NET MVC on Windows 7, and the browsers are Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: That looks like where the 4MB limit is coming from ... https://forums.asp.net/post/5011844.aspx  ... Web.config settings:  maxRequestLength : The default value is 4096 (4 MB). ... see link for solution.

Comment: The example at the link shows the configuration, allowing uploads of file/chucks up to 100MB

Comment: @Wayne Thanks a lot ;)